# Issue with anonymous threads multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

I have issue with the order of execution of methods of an instance through multiple threads.

I have my class and thread structures as mentioned below.

For the instance of `MainObj`, the method `lastExcec()` should get executed after `thirdExec()`.
The method `thirdExec()` is invoked by a thread sequence which spun 3 levels of anonymous thread.
The mehtod `lastExcec()` is invoked by another thread that was started later but with one level of anonymous thread.

```
//The class that initiates the process
ThreadExecuter
{
 ThreadExecuter()
 {
  MainObj anObj = new MainObj();
  .
  .
  .
  .
  anObj.lastExec();
 }
}

// The class that has the in which the mentioned methods present
MainObj
{

// first get executed from constructor through anon thread.
 MainObj()
 {
  new Thread()
  {
   run()
   {
    firstExec();
   }
  }
 }

// first executes second through anon thread
 firstExec()
 {
  new Thread()
  {
   run()
   {
    secExec();
   }
  }
 }

//sec executes third through an anonymous thread
 secExec()
 {
  new Thread()
  {
   run()
   {
    thirdExec();
   }
  }
 } 

 thirdExec()
 {
 }
// last should be executed after thrid
 lastExcec()
 {
 }
}
```

Comment: Why would inner classes affect the order a `Thread` executes in? Also, where do you call `start()`?

Comment: Okay. Actually make an attempt at your homework, and then come back and ask if you get stuck on some specific issue.

Comment: MainObj and ThreadExecuter are 2 different classes. Not inner class.

Comment: This code does not seem like Java to me.

Comment: I just wrote the skeleton.

Answer (score 1):

> I have issue with the order of execution of methods of an instance through multiple threads.

The whole point of writing multithreaded applications is that the threads work asynchronously and in parallel.  If you need or want a specific order to the operations then you usually need to write code to ensure it.

In your case, I believe you are asking why the `lastExcec()` method is called by the main thread *before* the other thread's methods are called.  This is because the main thread is probably not waiting for the other thread's to finish.  It forks the sub-threads and continues on executing in parallel with them.  It is typical for the `Thread.start()` method to take some time so `lastExec()` may be called before any other threads actually start executing.

If you need to wait for a particular thread then you will need to use `thread.join()` to join with it.  This is difficult with your code because the thread objects are anonymous and are created inside of `MainObj`.

One more comment.  It is considered a bad pattern to fork threads in object constructors.  This is because most likely you are leaking references to `this` to other threads which may work with the object before it is fully constructed.  It would be better to add a `start()` method on `MainObj` which actually starts the thread that was created in the constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Is there a way that Synchronization using a object lock would help me?

Comment: Uh it could but if you need to wait for the thread to finish then you should do so.  Lock objects help multiple threads coordinate access to a resource.  It depends on what you are trying to do.